# how to send a request to jsp from servlet after 10 seconds

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how to send a request from servlet to jsp after a gap of some seconds
i am uploading an image into the server.but i have observed that image is getting created in my server directory after 10 sec.
when I read after uploading image is not getting displayed.
so is there a way in which after some seconds i can tranfer the request from servlet to jsp

Answer (score 0):

[`Thread.sleep();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) will do. Also consider request time-out scenario. or if you can go with ajax-polling mechanism it would be better.

Comment: It will if placed at appropriate position